# Php. alexa

Tags: php

Привет, вот мой кусок кода

```
preg_match_all("/<a href=\"\/siteinfo\/*[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/is", $cllk, $keywords, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Вот url, откуда парсит сайты: **www.alexa.com/search?q=love&r=site_screener&p=bigtop**

Но что-то ни так работает, ни как не могу понять что ни так...
Парсит оба куска страницы..

```
<li>
<div class="site-listing">
<a href="/siteinfo/love.hu" class="title"><strong>love.hu</strong></a><br/>
<ul class="stats">
<li class="rank-graph rank-5">
<a href="/siteinfo/love.hu"><img src="http://pcache.alexa.com/images/rankometer/5.8e7be6744d9caa39e1a2c494d4f50dee.png" alt="love.hu is a  top 50,000 site" width='50' height='8'/>&nbsp;</a>
</li>
```

Помогите доработать скрипт, чтобы грабил url только от сюда

```
<a href="/siteinfo/love.hu" class="title"><strong>love.hu</strong></a><br/>
```

Нужно убрать каким-то образом все-что заключено в `<li class="rank-graph rank-5">*</li>`

Answer (score 1):

```
$test = '<li>
<div class="site-listing">
<a href="/siteinfo/love.hu" class="title"><strong>love.hu</strong></a><br/>
<ul class="stats">
<li class="rank-graph rank-5">
<a href="/siteinfo/love.hu"><img src="http://pcache.alexa.com/images/rankometer/5.8e7be6744d9caa39e1a2c494d4f50dee.png" alt="love.hu is a  top 50,000 site" width="50" height="8"/>&nbsp;</a>
</li>';

preg_match_all("/<a href=\"\/siteinfo\/*[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/is", $test, $keywords, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

//var_dump($keywords[0][0]);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($keywords[0][0]);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodeList = $xpath->query('//a/@href');
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodeList->length; $i++) {
    # Xpath query for attributes gives a NodeList containing DOMAttr objects.
    # http://php.net/manual/en/class.domattr.php
    echo $nodeList->item($i)->value;
}
```